# How do I apply conditional processing based on a prior row value per group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, conditional-statements

I have a table like the below:

| account | month | bad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 |  |
| a | 2 | y |
| a | 3 |  |
| a | 4 |  |
| a | 5 | y |
| b | 1 |  |
| b | 2 | y |
| b | 3 | y |
| b | 4 |  |

And I want to calculate a column that flags whether any account has been bad in an earlier month as so:

| account | month | bad | been_bad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 |  |  |
| a | 2 | y | y |
| a | 3 |  | y |
| a | 4 |  | y |
| a | 5 | y | y |
| b | 1 |  |  |
| b | 2 | y | y |
| b | 3 | y | y |
| b | 4 |  | y |

Seems like a simple problem but I am struggling to think of an easy way to solve this. I assume I would need to group by account, then use something that says: if bad == 'y' then 'y' else  in a kind of recurred loop. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution, based on the idea of propagating last valid observation forward to next valid ([`pandas.DataFrame.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)):

```
df['been_bad'] = df.groupby('account')['bad'].ffill()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  account  month  bad been_bad
0       a      1  NaN      NaN
1       a      2    y        y
2       a      3  NaN        y
3       a      4  NaN        y
4       a      5    y        y
5       b      1  NaN      NaN
6       b      2    y        y
7       b      3    y        y
8       b      4  NaN        y
```

Comment: This is a great idea - but does not work for what I am trying to do since ffill works on null values only and my actual use case has " " strings as opposed to NaN where bad != 'y'. 

I suppose I could get around that by converting to NaN then using ffill.. but I've faced nuances of this kind of problem before and would be great to get a more robust solution to this kind of problem. 

I will upvote anyway as it does present a fairly clean solution to the problem I posted. thanks @PaulS

Comment: Apparently, it works fine, even with `""` strings, @cgoldie: `df.bad = df.bad.fillna('')
df.bad = df.bad.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
df['been_bad'] = df.groupby('account')['bad'].ffill()
df`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `boolean` mask to find the `y`'s then use `argmax` and slicing to propagate that value:

**Starting with this extended data**

```
   account  month bad 
0        a      1     
1        a      2   y 
2        a      3     
3        a      4     
4        a      5   y 
5        b      1     
6        b      2   y 
7        b      3   y 
8        b      4     
9        c      1     
10       c      2     
11       c      3     
12       c      4
```

**Function Definition**

```
def f(x, bad='y'):
    m = (x==bad)
    
    if m.any():
        rc = x.copy()  # Don't modify the passed arg
        rc.iloc[m.argmax():] = rc.iat[m.argmax()]
        return rc
        
    return x
```

**Execute**

```
df['been_bad'] = df.groupby('account')['bad'].apply(f)
print(df)
```

**Result**

```
   account  month bad been_bad
0        a      1             
1        a      2   y        y
2        a      3            y
3        a      4            y
4        a      5   y        y
5        b      1             
6        b      2   y        y
7        b      3   y        y
8        b      4            y
9        c      1             
10       c      2             
11       c      3             
12       c      4
```